# dijkstra's algorithm - in c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra

for the past four days I am trying to understand the dijkstra's algorithm. But I can't. I have a vector of points. From that I created a cost matrix. But I don't know how to make the dijkstra's algorithm. Sources are available in net, but I am not from Computer science background, So I can't understand them. I am trying to make a function like this

```
vector<int> dijkstra(costMatrix[][])
{
  ....
  ....
  return vector<int>pathPointindex
}

main()
{
    vector<Point> availablePoints;
    costMatrix[][]=createCostMatrix();
    vector<int> indexes=dijikstra(costMatrix)
    for(int i=0;i<indexes.size();i++)
       cout << "path points are " << availablePoints[indexes[i]] << endl;
}
```

If anybody, can you please post the code. I am not lazy. But my project already crossed the deadline one day ago. Now I lost my hope to understand the logic. Now Just I want the function. "A man in need is the angel indeed" .

**EDIT:** Special thanks to "Loki astari" for his excellent answer

Comment: Do you know the actual algorithm itself - is it just the C++ that is tripping you up? If you do not know the algorithm, reading the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) page could help; especially the [psuedo-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode) section.

Comment: Try doing fractions of the algorithm and then try to put it together. 
Dijkstras is hard in the beginning. Just asking for the complete code will probably not help you that much in the end.

Comment: I just don't get why many good questions get closed while the ones like this  just asking to paste the code get 10 upvotes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I advise you to look at [TopCoder](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=graphsDataStrucs3) tutorial that have very pragmatic apporach.
You will need to find out how STL priority queue works and make sure you don't have any `negative edge weights` in your graph.

Decent full implementation can be found [here](http://zobayer.blogspot.com/2009/12/dijkstras-algorithm-in-c.html). You will have to add Path vector to it and implement `RecoverPath` method in order to get nodes on path from source to sink. To use this solution you will also need to convert your `adjacency matrix` to `adjacency list` in following way:

```
for (int i=0;i<nNodes;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<nNodes;j++){
        if (costMatrix[i][j] != NO_EDGE_VALUE){
            G[i].pb(make_pair(j,costMatrix[i],[j]));
        }
    }
```

EDIT: If your graph is dense I would advise you to use [Ford Bellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) algorithm is much simpler and shouldn't be much slower.

EDIT2: To calculate path you should add in the header

```
int P[MAX]; /*array with links to parents*/
for(i=0; i<=nodes; i++) P[i] = -1; /*magic unset value*/

// dijkstra
while(!Q.empty()) {
    ....
    if(!F[v] && D[u]+w < D[v]) {
        D[v] = D[u] + w;
        /*By setting P[v] value we will remember what is the 
          previous node on path from source */
        P[v] = u; // <-- added line
        Q.push(pii(v, D[v]));
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you have to add RecoverPath method (it works only when path exists)

```
vector<int> RecoverPath(int src, int dest){
    vector<int> path;
    int v = dest;
    while (v != src) {
        path.push_back(v);
        v = P[v];
    }
    path.push_back(src);
    std::reverse(path.begin(),path.end());
    return path;
}
```

Comment: in the above link, which is matrix row,column,and value
like 
matrix[row][column]=value

Comment: in this implementation instead of costMatrix you have vector< pii > G[MAX]; where G[x] holds out edges of x node, so to get matrix[row][col] you have to search G[row] for col value and return its cost.

Comment: Many thanks for the link,It's working, but i am getting the distance from source node to the others Oly. Can you please say how can I get the corresponding node numbers which are in those paths in the form of vector<vector<int>>.

Answer (score 41):

#### Dijkstra’s algorithm

In English:

This is an algorithm for finding the shortest route from point A to point B.
In computing terms we simplify the route to a graph consisting of nodes and arcs. Each node represents an intermediate point while each arc connect two nodes and has a (non negative) weight representing the cost to traverse between the two nodes.

To implement the algorithm you need two lists:

- finished: A set of (node,cost) where you have computed the minimum cost to reach.
- working:  A sorted list of (node,cost) that have been checked.

Algorithm:

```
working.addNode(Start, 0); // No cost to get to start.

for( (node, cost) = working.popHead(); node != End; (node,cost) = working.popHead())
{
    // If we have already processed this node ignore it.
    if (finished.find(node))
    {    continue;
    }

    // We have just removed a node from working.
    // Because it is the top of the list it is guaranteed to be the shortest route to
    // the node. If there is another route to the node it must go through one of the
    // other nodes in the working list which means the cost to reach it will be higher
    // (because working is sorted). Thus we have found the shortest route to the node.

    // As we have found the shortest route to the node save it in finished.
    finished.addNode(node,cost);

    // For each arc leading from this node we need to find where we can get to.
    foreach(arc in node.arcs())
    {
        dest = arc.dest();
        if (NOT (finished.find(dest)))
        {
            // If the node is already in finished then we don't need to worry about it
            // as that will be the shortest route other wise calculate the cost and add
            // this new node to the working list.
            destCost = arc.cost() + cost;
            working.addNode(dest,destCost); // Note. Working is sorted list
        }
    }
}
```

So if you think about this algorithm. Say you are traveling from London to Manchester.

```
finished = {} // empty.
working  = { (London,0) }
```

Using the following Costs matrix:

```
                  L    S    O    B    N    M    W
(L) ondon         -    50   60   100  130  -    -
(S) outhampton    50   -    70   -    -    -    -
(O) xford         60   70   -    50   -    200  -
(B) irmingham     100  -    50   -    -    80   110
(N) orwich        130  -    -    -    -    -    -
(M) anchester     -    -    200  80   -    -    80
Ne(W) castle      -    -    -    110  -    80   -
```

Now you take London out of the working list (as it is at the head) and place it into the finished list. Then add to the working list all the towns directly connected to London.

```
finished = { (London,0) }
working  = { (Southampton, 50), (Oxford, 60), (Birmingham, 100), (Norwich,130) }
```

Consider the towns in the working set the outer edge of a bubble that has expanded from London. The job of Dijkstra's algorithm is to keep expanding the bubble until we hit Manchester (without retracing any steps we have already taken). So the bubble always expands outwards and we always expand the part of the bubble that is smallest.

So the next step is to take the head of the list and repeat. From Southampton there are only two destinations. Back to London (which we discard as it is in the finished list) and Oxford. The cost to get to Oxford is 50 + the cost from Southampton to Oxford (so notice it is in the working list twice but don;t worry we will discard it later as not an optimal route).

```
finished = { (London,0), (Southampton,50) }
working  = { (Oxford, 60), (Birmingham, 100), (Oxford, 120), (Norwich,130) }
```

So repeat the loop. The head of the list is Oxford. From Oxford we can go to Manchester(200), Birmingham(50) or back to London(60) or Southampton(Remember we need to add the cost of getting to oxford to each of these costs above. Note that from Oxford we could have gone to Southampton but we have already found the shortest route to Southampton so no processing is required) This will leave us with:

```
finished = { (London,0), (Southampton,50), (Oxford, 60) }
working  = { (Birmingham, 100), (Birmingham,110), (Oxford, 120), (Norwich,130), (Manchester,200)}
```

Notice we have Manchester in the working list now (this is our destination). But we need to keep working as we may find a shorter route. So now we expand from Birmingham. From there we can go to Oxford(50), Manchester(80), London(100), Newcastle(110). Adding the cost of getting to Birmingham in the first place this gives us:

```
finished = { (London,0), (Southampton,50), (Oxford, 60), (Birmingham, 100) }
working  = { (Birmingham,110), (Oxford, 120), (Norwich,130), {Manchester, 180), (Manchester,200), (Newcastle, 210)}
```

The next two nodes. Oxford and Birmingham are already in the finished list so we can ignore them. So unless there is a route from Norwich to Manchester that is less than 50 miles we will reach Manchester in the iteration after that.

Comment: York 
 Fantastic. I suspect you must be a computer science professor or else those universities are unlucky who didn't get you as a professor.

 Now I clearly understood. But you made me to land in a problamatic situation. 

  In the above answer jethro gave me the code which is working fine for my problem( A temporary solution ). But your's is  parmanent solution. Now to whom I have to tick the green mark. How can I say which eye is my best eye.

   You yourself decide,(you are having 34.4k reputaion, jethro is having 90 only) to whom I have to tick the green mark.

Comment: @prabhakaran: jethro has real code. Teodor Pripoae has what looks like a real program. I only provide an algorithm. You should choose the one that helps you the most (in relation to the question). An extra 15 points is not going to change my status much either way.

Comment: Martin, thanks for this. It's really well written and explained.

Comment: Even though it's not real code, it's close enough that I could implement it line for line with a priority queue (using negative value for distance) and pairs. Thanks for one of the cleanest "c++" implementation of dijkstra I've came across yet.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <limits> 
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;


typedef int vertex_t;
typedef double weight_t;

const weight_t max_weight = numeric_limits<double>::infinity();

struct neighbor {
    vertex_t target;
    weight_t weight;
    neighbor(vertex_t arg_target, weight_t arg_weight)
        : target(arg_target), weight(arg_weight) { }
};

typedef vector<vector<neighbor> > adjacency_list_t;

// Computing the shortest pathway

void
DijkstraComputePaths(vertex_t source,
                     const adjacency_list_t &adjacency_list,
                     vector<weight_t> &min_distance,
                     vector<vertex_t> &previous)
{
    int n = adjacency_list.size();
    min_distance.clear();
    min_distance.resize(n, max_weight);
    min_distance[source] = 0;
    previous.clear();
    previous.resize(n, -1);
    set<pair<weight_t, vertex_t> > vertex_queue;
    vertex_queue.insert(make_pair(min_distance[source], source));

    while (!vertex_queue.empty())
    {
        weight_t dist = vertex_queue.begin()->first;
        vertex_t u = vertex_queue.begin()->second;
        vertex_queue.erase(vertex_queue.begin());

        // Visit each edge exiting u
        const vector<neighbor> &neighbors = adjacency_list[u];
        for (vector<neighbor>::const_iterator neighbor_iter = neighbors.begin();
            neighbor_iter != neighbors.end();
            neighbor_iter++)
        {
            vertex_t v = neighbor_iter->target;
            weight_t weight = neighbor_iter->weight;
            weight_t distance_through_u = dist + weight;
            if (distance_through_u < min_distance[v]) {
                vertex_queue.erase(make_pair(min_distance[v], v));

                min_distance[v] = distance_through_u;
                previous[v] = u;
                vertex_queue.insert(make_pair(min_distance[v], v));

            }
        }
    } // while
}
```

Comment: Welcome new joinee. See the date of the question

Comment: It's never too late to add an answer as it might help someone in the future and it might be yourself as it has already happened for people who came back to find their own answers.

Answer (score 2):

The main idea of Dijkstra algorithm is rather simple:
Suppose you have a set of points with a known shortest paths to a given point A.
Then lets assume we want to add a new point C to a set.
Lets find which points from the set are connected with a point we want to add.
Let it be point's B(i)
So for all point's B(i) we will new to find a sum of distance between A to B(i) and B(i) and C. The smallest of that distances will be the minimum between A and C.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation in c ++

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#define pb push_back
#define mp make_pair
#define MAXN 50100
#define INF 1000000000

int N, M, d[MAXN]; vector<int> G[MAXN], C[MAXN];
set< pair<int, int> > T;

void solve(void)
{
    int i, j, k, val, x;

    for(i = 2; i <= N; i++) d[i] = INF;
    T.insert( mp(0, 1) );

    while( T.size() > 0 )
    {
        val = (*T.begin()).first, x = (*T.begin()).second;
        T.erase(*T.begin());
        for(i = 0; i < G[x].size(); i++)
         if(d[ G[x][i] ] > val + C[x][i] )
            d[ G[x][i] ] = val + C[x][i], T.insert(mp(d[G[x][i]],G[x][i]));
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    freopen("dijkstra.in", "rt", stdin);
    freopen("dijkstra.out", "wt", stdout);

    int i, a, b, c;

    scanf("%d %d\n", &N, &M);

    for(i = 1; i <= M; i++)
        scanf("%d %d %d\n", &a, &b, &c), G[a].pb(b), C[a].pb(c);

    solve();

    for(i = 2; i <= N; i++)
        printf("%d ", d[i] == INF ? 0 : d[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd upvote this, but the naming of the variable is terrible. It's pretty much obfuscated code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<map>
#include<queue>


using namespace std;

const size_t INT_MAX = 0xFFFFFFFF; // or any other value representing infinite distance.
```

first create a struct edge containing the source node index, destination node index and the edge "weight"( length ).

```
struct edge { size_t from; size_t to; size_t length; };
```

define a class Node containing edges to adjacent neighbors.

```
class Node 
{ 
public:
    void AddNeighborEdge( edge _NeighborEdge ) { m_neighborsEdges.push_back( _NeighborEdge ); } 
    vector<edge>::iterator FirstNeighborEdge() { return  m_neighborsEdges.begin(); }
    vector<edge>::iterator LastNeighborEdge() { return  m_neighborsEdges.end(); }

private: 
     vector<edge>  m_neighborsEdges; 
};
```

class NeighborsDistanceUpdator would be used as a "functor" by the for_each algorithm, for iterative pass and update of min distance from current node in the graph to adjacent neighbors.

```
class NeighborsDistanceUpdator
{
public:
    NeighborsDistanceUpdator( vector<size_t>& _min_distance_from_source, queue< size_t >& _nodes_to_visit ) : m_min_distance_from_source( _min_distance_from_source ),                                                              m_nodes_to_visit( _nodes_to_visit ) 
                                                            {} 
    void operator()( edge& _edge )
    {   
        size_t from = _edge.from;
        size_t to = _edge.to;

        if ( m_min_distance_from_source[ to ] > m_min_distance_from_source[ from ] + _edge.length ) 
        {
            m_min_distance_from_source[ to ] = m_min_distance_from_source[ from ] + _edge.length;
            m_nodes_to_visit.push( to );
        }
    }    

private:
    vector<size_t>& m_min_distance_from_source;
    queue< size_t >& m_nodes_to_visit;
};
```

as for the dijkstra algorithm, just run over all nodes in the graph and for each node update the min distance from source ( if less ), while saving adjacent nodes to visit.

```
size_t dijkstra( map< size_t, Node  >& _graph, size_t _sourceIndex, size_t _targetIndex ) 
{
    vector<size_t> min_distance_from_source( _graph.size(), INT_MAX );
    min_distance_from_source[ _sourceIndex ] = 0;
    queue< size_t > nodes_to_visit;
    nodes_to_visit.push( _sourceIndex );
    NeighborsDistanceUpdator neighborsDistanceUpdator( min_distance_from_source, nodes_to_visit );

    while ( ! nodes_to_visit.empty() ) 
    {

        size_t currNodeIndex = nodes_to_visit.front();

        if ( currNodeIndex ==  _targetIndex ) return min_distance_from_source[ currNodeIndex ];

        nodes_to_visit.pop();

        vector<edge>::iterator firstNeighborEdge= _graph[ currNodeIndex ].FirstNeighborEdge();
        vector<edge>::iterator lastNeighborEdge= _graph[ currNodeIndex ].LastNeighborEdge();

        for_each( firstNeighborEdge, lastNeighborEdge, neighborsDistanceUpdator );
    }
    return INT_MAX;
}
```

test...

```
int main()
{
    Node node1;
    Node node2;
    Node node3;
    Node node4;

    map< size_t, Node > graph;
    edge ed;

    ed.from = 0;
    ed.to = 1;
    ed.length = 1;
    node1.AddNeighborEdge( ed );

    cout << "node: " << 0 << " to: " << ed.to ;
    cout << " lenth: " << ed.length << endl << endl;

    ed.from = 0;        
    ed.to = 2;
    ed.length = 4;
    node1.AddNeighborEdge( ed );
    graph.insert( make_pair( 0, node1 ) );

    cout << "node: " << 0 << " to: " << ed.to ;
    cout << " lenth: " << ed.length << endl << endl;

    ed.from = 1;
    ed.to = 2;
    ed.length = 1;
    node2.AddNeighborEdge( ed );

    cout << "node: " << 1 << " to: " << ed.to ;
    cout << " lenth: " << ed.length << endl << endl;

    ed.from = 1;
    ed.to = 3;
    ed.length = 3;
    node2.AddNeighborEdge( ed );
    graph.insert( make_pair( 1, node2 ) );

    cout << "node: " << 1 << " to: " << ed.to ;
    cout << " lenth: " << ed.length << endl << endl;

    ed.from = 2;
    ed.to = 3;
    ed.length = 1;
    node3.AddNeighborEdge( ed );
    graph.insert( make_pair( 2, node3 ) );

    cout << "node: " << 2 << " to: " << ed.to ;
    cout << " lenth: " << ed.length << endl << endl;

    ed.from = 3;
    ed.to = INT_MAX;
    ed.length = INT_MAX;
    node3.AddNeighborEdge( ed );
    graph.insert( make_pair( 3, node4 ) );

    cout << "node: " << 2 << " to: " << ed.to ;
    cout << " lenth: " << ed.length << endl << endl;


    cout << "min length from: 1 to 4 = " << dijkstra( graph, 0,3  ) << endl;
}
```